# How to hide my ip address?

Tags: magento-1.9

I would like to know how to hide my ip address I often go on my website and it is not very good for my statistics

Comment: What do you mean by hide? So in google analytics don't track your IP address?

Comment: This is not to follow my ip in google analytics

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't really relate to magento but i have an answer for you anyways. 
You can exclude traffic via IP in google analytics by doing the following:

To exclude internal traffic from appearing in a report view, create a custom filter to exclude a specific IP address or a range of IP addresses.

Filter Type: Custom > Exclude

Filter Field: IP Address

Filter Pattern:

Remember to use regular expressions to enter an IP address.

For example, if the single IP address is 176.168.1.1, then enter 176.168.1.1.

For example, if the range of IP addresses is 176.168.1.1-25 and 10.0.0.1-14, then enter
^176.168.1.([1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-5])$|^10.0.0.([1-9]|1[0-4])$

source: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034840?hl=en

Answer (score 2):

An easier, and more permanent solution, is to install the Google Analytics Opt-out Browser Add-on. This will keep you from being tracked by Google Analytics, for the site you are working on now and any in the future.

If, for some reason, you want to be tracked by GA again, just disable the add-on.

You can download the add-on for all (major) browsers here : https://tools.google.com/dlpage/gaoptout